# Windows Batch: problem running command after IF-ELSE clause

Tags: windows, batch-file, python-venv

I've encounted a very strange issue with .bat script in Win10:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST ".\venv\" (
    ECHO | SET /p msg="Creating virtual environment..."
    python -m venv venv
    ECHO OK
    venv\Scripts\activate.bat
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
    pip install -r requirements.txt
) ELSE (
    venv\Scripts\activate.bat
)
python runner.py
```

The last command `python runner.py` is never executed.
However, if I duplicate the command in `IF` and `ELSE` clauses, then it runs OK.
What could be the reason for this?

P.S. I tried using `IF-GOTO` and `GOTO` in `IF-ELSE` clause -- nothing. Looks like the script finishes with closing bracket and that's it. And looks like the problem is in `venv\Scripts\activate.bat`.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason are these lines, that you have in both "then" and "else" parts:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

This line means to execute *another Batch file*. If you want that after executing the other Batch file, the control flow returns to the line below, then you must execute it as a "subroutine" via the `call` command:

```
call venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Otherwise, when the other Batch file ends (`activate.bat`), the process will end at that point.

Comment: Thanks, `call`ing .bat has helped. But it's strange that `python -m ...` and `pip install -r ...` were executing fine all the time

Comment: Well, yes. That is because the _whole_ block of commands enclosed in parentheses are first parsed and stored in memory, so these commands are executed anyway when the other Batch file ends.

Answer (score 1):

Control does not return to parent scripts by default, so when you run a second script from inside of a batch file, the parent script is effectively terminated.

You can have the second script run in a child process by using the `call` command. This way, once the second script is done, flow returns to the parent script.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST ".\venv\" (
    ECHO | SET /p msg="Creating virtual environment..."
    python -m venv venv
    ECHO OK
    call venv\Scripts\activate.bat
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
    pip install -r requirements.txt
) ELSE (
    venv\Scripts\activate.bat
)
python runner.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably has to do with some magic that virtualenv's activate script does, like creating a new shell so your main script does not continue.

Not sure if this will work but in a similar script I could do make it work by executing the next commands concatenated with &, you may try something like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST ".\venv\" (
    ECHO | SET /p msg="Creating virtual environment..."
    python -m venv venv
    ECHO OK
    venv\Scripts\activate.bat & (python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools && pip install -r requirements.txt && python runner.py)
) ELSE (
    venv\Scripts\activate.bat & python runner.py
)
```

Comment: Yes, separating statements with `&` works and I used it at first, but I find this very ugly